How can you retreive all the reports which use row-level security on a Power BI Report Server?
For example in the SQL view [PBIRS].[dbo].[ExecutionLog3] you can find the logging, but I haven't found any table or view with a boolean or something to indicate that Row-level security is in use. Where can I find that for all the 300+ reports at once?


In the end I received a clue to the answer here: https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Report-Server/Retreive-the-use-of-Row-level-security/m-p/3896924#M34829
With that I was able to make below loop;
# Define variables
$webPortalURL = "https://example.com/ReportsPowerBI"
$PBI_Reports_Array = @()
$PBI_Reports_Array = $(Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials -uri $($webPortalURL + "/api/v2.0/PowerBIReports"))
$loopCount = 0 
$RoleAssignments = @()
# Loop through all Power BI reports 
foreach ($reportPath in $PBI_Reports_Array.value.path) {
    try {
        $RoleAssignmentsPath = $ReportServerUri + "/api/v2.0/PowerBIReports(Path='" + $reportPath + "')/DataModelRoleAssignments";
        $RolesPath = $ReportServerUri + "/api/v2.0/PowerBIReports(Path='" + $reportPath + "')/DataModelRoles";
        #call API - row level security
        $RoleAssignments += $(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $RoleAssignmentsPath -ContentType "application/json" -UseDefaultCredentials -Method Get);
        #call API - RLS role
        #$Roles = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $RolesPath -ContentType "application/json" -UseDefaultCredentials -Method Get

        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($($RoleAssignments[$loopCount].value))) { 
            write-host "$loopCount | $reportPath | No DataModelRoleAssignments for this report!"; 
        }
        else {
            write-host "$loopCount | $reportPath | $($RoleAssignments[$loopCount].value.GroupUserName)" -foregroundcolor magenta;
        }

        $loopCount++;
    }
    catch {

    }
}

